# Salesforce Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created a pre-release org for Lightning Web Component development.
One of my team member is using same org for Lightning web component development. My team member has push LWC in org.
I want to retrieve that component in my Visual studio code instance.
Please help me to resolve this problem and what steps should I follow.
I have retrieved all classes in VSC.
Urgent suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

This will be simply a three step process:-

Create a project first:-

- In Visual Studio code, press Command + Shift + P on a Mac or Ctrl +
  Shift + P on Windows. Type SFDX.
- Select SFDX: Create Project.
- Enter (enter any name you want) as the project name.
- Press Enter.
- Select a folder to store the project.
- Click Create Project.

Authorize Your Developer Edition As an Org in VS Code

- In Visual Studio Code, press Command + Shift + P on a Mac or Ctrl +
  Shift + P on Windows. Type SFDX.
- Select SFDX: Authorize an Org.
- Press Enter to accept the Project Default login URL option.
- Press Enter to accept the default alias.
- Log in using your pre-release org credentials.
- Click Allow.

Now Right-click the default folder and select **SFDX: Retrieve source from org**

Or Via terminal window, Run this command from the command line.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -p <pathToRetrieve> -u <orgUserName>
```

It will bring the things for you.

You can refer these:- 
[Quick Start: Lightning Web Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components)